# apache poi: header does not load correctly

Tags: java, header, apache-poi, xwpf

I have here a header [header template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNOzS.png) saved in a Word document (Dok3.docx). I am loading this Word document as an XWPFDocument. I am copying the header from this Word document to a new Word document (CreateWordHeader.docx). But the header does not load correctly [incorrect header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3bYB.png). As you can see, the image is not loaded, and the format of the header is a mess.  And when opening the generated CreatWordHeader Word document, i get the error: `Word found unreadable content error.`Anyone an idea?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();
        XWPFHeader header = doc.createHeader(HeaderFooterType.DEFAULT);
        header.setHeaderFooter(loadHeader().getHeaderArray(0)._getHdrFtr());
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CreateWordHeader.docx");
        doc.write(out);
        out.close();
        doc.close();

    }

    private static XWPFDocument loadHeader() {
        try {
            return new XWPFDocument(Objects.requireNonNull(Main.class.getClassLoader().
                    getResourceAsStream("Dok3.docx")));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: "I am copying the header from this Word document to a new Word document": No.you are only copying the `org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTHdrFtr` from one `XWPFHeaderFooter` to the other. But that `CTHdrFtr` only contains the XML of `/word/header1.xml` which **links** to the picture in `/word/media` and **links** to the styles in `/word/styles.xml` in the `*.docx` ZIP archive .

Comment: okay, and how can i then ilustrate the exact header template with the picture and the exact format in the generated word document?